# How to draw a double continous arrowhead [tikz]

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw lines with double arrowheads which continously following each other (e.g. torque in mechanics)

Now I draw two following lines which complete each other like

```
\draw[] (0,0) edge[-triangle 45] (0.8,0) edge[-triangle 45] (1,0);
```

[image]

Is there an easier way to do this? AFAIK there are no default double axial arrowheads in tikz. So I want to avoid to adjust coordinates of both lines to make arrowheads continous.

Comment: From manual: `\pgfarrowsdeclaredouble[⟨offset⟩]{⟨start name⟩}{⟨end name⟩}{⟨old start name⟩}{⟨old end name⟩} This command is a shortcut for combining an arrow kind with itself.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a command for declaring double arrow tips:

```
\pgfarrowsdeclaredouble[distance between tips]{new start name}{new end name}{start arrow tip}{end arrow tip}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfarrowsdeclaredouble[-\pgflinewidth]{caniko}{caniko}{triangle 45}{triangle 45}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [-caniko] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Jake, my congratulations for the 100,000 :-)